# Is $\frac{1010103010101}9$ prime or composite?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$1010103010101$ obviously divisible by $9$.

> Is $\frac{1010103010101}9$ prime or composite?

The answer would be obtained without using WolframAlpha

Comment: I suppose with some ingenuity you might light on $1000101\cdot1010001$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The polynomial $ x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 3x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 $ can be factored through the following manipulations:

$$x^3 (x^3 + x^2 + 1) + x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = (x^3 + 1)(x^3 + x^2 + 1) + x^4 + x^3 + x = (x^3 + x + 1)(x^3 + x^2 + 1) $$

Now, plug in $ x = 10^2 $ to get a factorization of your number, which easily confirms that your number is composite.

Answer (score 2):

You might find that "funny mirror pattern" is close to some "funny mirro pattern" squared. Indeed, for digits $a,b$, we have $(a0b0\ldots)^2=a^202ab0\ldots$, so to match this with $1010\ldots$ or more generally with $x0x0\ldots$,  we ought to have $a=2b$. The simplest case of this is $a=2$, $b=1$. It turns out that $2010102^2=4040510050404$ is just $980100000$ more that $4\cdot 1010103010101$. And $9801$ is recognozed as $10000-200+1=(100-1)^2$. So you get some factors from $4\cdot 1010103010101=a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.